# Cant refresh data in ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a ListFragment with AsynchTaskLoader that contains datasource but I have trouble in refreshing listFragment as it doesnt get refresh when I change data from background in my BaseAsyncTaskLoader

The code is attached:

**The Activity that loads listfragment**

```
public class BaseFragmentManager extends FragmentActivity implements ListItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_stack);

        Button btnLoadMore = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_fragment);
        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("com.test.gcc.myintent.loader.BaseAsyncTaskLoader");
                i.putExtra("action", "loadmore");
                sendBroadcast(i);
            }
        });

        BaseListFragmentActivity fragment = new BaseListFragmentActivity();
         FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
         transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemSelected(int index) {
        Log.i("Error", "itemSelected-"+index);
    }

}
```

**My LISTFragment class that is not being refreshed**

```
public class BaseListFragmentActivity extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<MyData>> {
    private ListItemSelectedListener selectedListener;
    private int index = 0;
    private ArrayList<MyData> data;
    private BaseAsyncTaskLoader astask;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;


    @Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        this.data = MyDataBroker.getDefaultBroker().getData();

        this.adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this.getActivity(), data);

        setListAdapter(this.adapter);
        setListShown(false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override public Loader<ArrayList<MyData>>  onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader with no arguments, so it is simple.
        astask = new BaseAsyncTaskLoader(this.getActivity());//new AppListLoader(getActivity());
        return astask;
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<MyData>> Loader, ArrayList<MyData> data) {
        this.adapter.setData(data);

         if (isResumed()) {
                setListShown(true);
            } else {
                setListShownNoAnimation(true);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        index = position;
        selectedListener.onListItemSelected(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ArrayList<MyData>> data) {
        adapter.setData(null);
    }

    public interface ListItemSelectedListener {
        public void onListItemSelected(int index);
    }
```

}

**AsynchTaskLoader Class**

```
public class BaseAsyncTaskLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<MyData>> {
    private ArrayList<MyData> data;
    private int pageNumber;
    private boolean listenerIsRegistered = false;
    private com.test.gcc.myintent.test.BaseAsyncTaskLoader.CustomBroadCastListener listener;

    public BaseAsyncTaskLoader(Context context) {
        super(context);
        pageNumber = 1;

        listener = new CustomBroadCastListener(); 
        if (!listenerIsRegistered) {
            context.registerReceiver(listener, new IntentFilter("com.test.gcc.myintent.loader.BaseAsyncTaskLoader"));
            listenerIsRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This is where the bulk of our work is done. This function is called in a
     * background thread and should generate a new set of data to be published
     * by the loader.
     */
    @Override
    public ArrayList<MyData> loadInBackground() {
        final Context context = getContext();

        return this.loadInBackgroud();

    }

    private ArrayList<MyData> loadInBackgroud() {

        return MyDataBroker.getDefaultBroker().getData(); //returns some data of custom type.
    }

    /**
     * Called when there is new data to deliver to the client. The super class
     * will take care of delivering it; the implementation here just adds a
     * little more logic.
     */
    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ArrayList<MyData> data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            if (data != null) {
                onReleaseResources(data);
            }
        }

        if (isStarted()) {
            super.deliverResult(data);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to start the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        if (this.data != null) {
            deliverResult(this.data);
        }

        if (takeContentChanged() || this.data == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to stop the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        // Attempt to cancel the current load task if possible.
        cancelLoad();
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to cancel a load.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ArrayList<MyData> data) {
        super.onCanceled(data);
        onReleaseResources(data);
    }

    /**
     * Handles a request to completely reset the Loader.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        super.onReset();
        onStopLoading();
        this.data = null;
    }

    public void onLoadMore(){
        this.loadInBackground();
    } 


    protected class CustomBroadCastListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals("com.test.gcc.myintent.loader.BaseAsyncTaskLoader")) {
                if(intent.getStringExtra("action") != null && 
                        intent.getStringExtra("action").equals("loadmore")){
                    loadInBackground();

                }
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated with an
     * actively loaded data set.
     */
    protected void onReleaseResources(List<MyData> apps) {      
        //NOTUSED
    }
}
```

From debug I can see that the data is being loaded but the listFragment doesn't refresh and as far I know we don't have to refresh listFragment manually as it is attached to data source it should be refreshed automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call restart loader instead in loadMOre and better call it from ListFragment

```
public void onLoadMore(){
        loader.restartLoader(0, null, this);
}
```

and changing the onFinished to as mentioned by @doorstuck

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<MyData>> Loader, ArrayList<MyData> data) {
    this.adapter.setData(data);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
     }
}
```

A better example can be found at [here](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-fragments-saving-state-and-screen-rotation/#comment-40)

Answer (score 5):

Call `invalidateViews()` to refresh `ListFragment`

```
listFragment.getListView().invalidateViews();
```

Comment: Is it defect in ListFragment? It does not work without invalidateViews even with notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to call:

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

In your list adapter when you want the views that are bound to the adapter to update. Please post the code to your list adapter.

You could put it here:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<MyData>> Loader, ArrayList<MyData> data) {
    this.adapter.setData(data);
    this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     if (isResumed()) {
            setListShown(true);
        } else {
            setListShownNoAnimation(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: where should I put notifyDataSetChange(), I used to use it in onResume in my ListActivity but in FragmentList onResume() doesnt gets called as the data is being changed in background thread and its called by asyncTask. I might have to remove the loader and implement my own code here.

Comment: The problem is that this part of code never runs the second time if I want it to. The onLoadFinished only gets called the first time if I change the content of the loader or want to load new data from web I will call loader.oncontentchange() thought this will load the new data but it wont call onLoadfinish in the listfragment . To call onload finish I will have to call oncreateloader after I have called the oncontentchange but that doesnt gets called in sequence so its useless. I only want to refresh list once the data is loaded from either force laod or oncontentchange.

Comment: Lets say I have a list of data which I loads from internet and from some link like http://mytestdata/page1 and I have a button in my list which says loadmoredata and I just keep changing page number each time I make request like http://mytestdata/page2 but at the same time I dont want my previous data to be deleted, the new data that I want to load from asynctaskloader should be added at the end of the list and just keeps on adding as i press loadmore each time. So that is what I want basically so any example or anything would be of great help thanks